# Loading two post layouts for the same post with different url

Tags: php

How can I show the same post content with two different post layouts on two different URLs?

For example

```
https://www.domain.com/help-brothers/post-layout-1/post-name
https://www.domain.com/help-brothers/post-layout-2/post-name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the layout name as a `GET` parameter and then change the design based on that. So your URL should be something like this:

```
http://domain.com/post-name?layout=layout-1
```

Now in your `single.php` file or whatever file that renders the template, you can do this check to show the different layouts:

```
<?php 
// If the header is different two, you should call for different headers too, 
// Check this for showing different headers
// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/
if( isset( $_GET['layout'] )  && $_GET['layout'] == 'layout-1' ) {
    // Show the design for for the first layout 
}
else if ( ... ) {
    // Show the design for other layouts 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it will work